# Error 11 on HAProxy startup - How to debug?

Tags: haproxy

I am running HaProxy on ubuntu 14.04. The system works, but I do get an alert during startup which I would like to debug:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/haproxy restart
 * Restarting haproxy haproxy  

[ALERT] 314/173551 (14318) : sendto logger #1 failed: Resource temporarily unavailable (errno=11)
```

It does unfortunatelly not tell which resource is unavailable. The config consists out of many resources.

How to determine the cause of this alert? Thank you for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

I found on the following link that restarting syslog could help:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.web.haproxy/4716
( Maybe also check /proc/sys/net/unix/max_dgram_qlen )

My max_dgram_qlen is 512 and after restarting syslog and haproxy via systemd it works.